# Approximation in calculation of capacitance of two non-parallel plates

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, approximations

This question is with reference to [another question of a similar title](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148283/capacitance-of-two-non-parallel-plates?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C58.0948), which has an answer.

In the most upvoted answer to the problem, it has been assumed that the capacitance of an infinitesimal segment is

$$ dC = \epsilon_0\frac{b~\mathrm{d}x}{l + x\tan \theta}$$

But I think this is flawed, since this is true only for very large plates for which the separation between the plates is small compared to the linear dimensions of the area of the plates. My question is, if this is justified, what is the justification? If not, what would be a more correct answer/method to this problem?

Comment: This is a problem the electrical engineers encounter.  If you do not make the assumptions that you have made above then one way is to move to finite element analysis. [Here is an example of such an analysis](https://riunet.upv.es/bitstream/handle/10251/102944/capacitance%20evaluation%20on%20non-parallel%20thick-plate....pdf?sequence=1)